# Understanding calculus by correlating time/distance with speed

Tags: calculus

Let's take free fall for example where gravity is 9.81 m/s^2, speed = gt and distance is = 0.5gt^2 where t is time in seconds. Let's say if you jump, you will reach max height and from that exact point in time, distance and speed are zero and we start from there.

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c} 
 \text{Time} & \text{Distance} & \text{Speed} \\ \hline
 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \hline
 1 & 4.905 & 9.81 \\ \hline
 2 & 19.62 & 19.62 \\ \hline
 3 & 44.145 & 29.43 \\ \hline
 4 & 78.48 & 39.24 \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

We can calculate speed using diff. calculus using the distance formula as our function then from 0.5gt^2 we just simplify to f(t) = 4.095t^2, it’s derivative is f’(t) = 9.81t. So we know that the instantaneous speed where t equals 4 is 39.24m/s.

What I seem to be missing is what dy/dx represents, if it represents the relation between time/distance and speed, let me give it a try and please tell me if this accurate:

The secant/slope (dy/dx) for points on the 2D plane: P1 (3,44.145), P2(4,78.48) is found by ((y2 – y1) / (x2 – x1)) = **24.525** and the correlation with speed is that if you average the speed at times 3 and 4 (39.24+29.43)/2 you get **24.525** and **that’s the correlation**, they are the same by means of it’s derivative! so the derivative is the rate of change of y with respect to x.

thanks for your time, I am trying hard to explain this to myself.

Comment: if you use the derivative to find the velocity you get instantaneous velocity  not average velocity. But  you are correct as $\frac{ds}{dt} = v$

Comment: as pranav says, it should only give instantaneous velocity. The reason you get the correct answer by averaging is because the acceleration is constant. _In general_ (i.e. when you might have non-constant acceleration), the derivative gives you the speed at any particular time if you take two points really close to this time period and average their $x,y$ values (as you have done). "very close" refers to the fact that the derivative is defined as a limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right. It can be shown mathematically. We have the following formula for the distance (constant acceleration $g$):

$$s(t)=\frac12\cdot g\cdot t^2 $$

First of all we calculate $$\frac{s_3-s_2}{t_3-t_2}=\frac12\cdot g\cdot \frac{ t_3^2-t_2^2}{t_3-t_2}=\frac12\cdot g\cdot (t_2+t_3)\quad(\color{blue}*)$$

At the last equality the third binomial formula has been applied. The next step is to calculate the derivative of $s(t)$ w.r.t. $t$

$$s'(t)=v(t)= g\cdot t $$

Then we get $$\frac{v_2+v_3}{2}=\frac12\cdot g\cdot (t_2+t_3)\quad(\color{blue}{**})$$

The two expressions $(*)$ and $(**)$ are equal.